# Finding Taylor polynomial about $x_{0}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a function such that $f(1)=-1$ , $f'(1)=2$ , $f''(1)=0$,
>   $f^{(3)}(x)=e^{x^2}$. Find the Taylor polynomial of degree 3 about $x_0=1$
>   for $f$.

I am missing $f(x)$ , $f'(x)$ , $f''(x)$ but I have $f^{(3)}(x)$ and I substitute 
$f^{(3)}(1)$ to get $e$.

Now that I have $f(1)$ , $f'(1)$ , $f''(1)$, $f^{(3)}(1)$ can I use the Taylor polynomial formula?

I applied the formula

$$f(x) = f(x_0) + \frac{f'(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$

and I get

$$f(x) = 1 + 2(x-2) + 0 +e (x-e)^3 / 6$$

Now I substitute $x = 1$ and I end up with

$$f(1) = -1+ e (1-e)^3 / 6$$

Am I doing this the correct way?

Comment: Why $e(x-e)^3/6$? $x_0\neq e$ it is $x_0=1$. Your final answer cannot be $f(1)$, it has to be $f(x)$!

Comment: @manooooh then can I ask what do you do with the x0? I am thinking that would replace e with 1 so (x-e)^3 with (x-1)^3 .Then you would end up with f(x)=1+2(x−2)+0+(x−1)^3/6 ? but please tell me what you do with the x0.

Comment: Note that the $k$-th derivative of $f$ usually is denoted by $f^{(k)}$, not $f^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question just asks for the Taylor polynomial for $f$, so you need not plug in $x=1$ afterwards. Applying the formula in the question with $x_0 = 1$, we get the Taylor polynomial

$$T(x) = -1 + 2(x - 1) + 0 + \frac{e}{6}(x-1)^3$$

and this should be what you're looking for.